# Show that $\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{dxdydz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2+1)^2}=\pi^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> How can I Show that $\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{dxdydz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2+1)^2}=\pi^2$

After making $x=\rho\sin \phi\cos\theta$, $y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta$, and $z=\rho\cos\phi$ we get $dxdydz=\rho^2\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$ so we have $$\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{dxdydz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2+1)^2}=\iiint \frac{\rho^2\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta}{(\rho^2+1)^2}$$ but I'm not sure on the new limits of integration to continue, any help?

Comment: Your new limits of integration will be $$0\leq \rho < \infty,0\leq \phi\leq \pi, 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$

Comment: The conversion is correct, think about this domain as a sphere: the smallest radius will be the centre where r=0 and you are going around the full axis so theta must vary from 0 to 2 pi and finally phi must also cover its full range. However to prevent overlap it is only necessary for this to go up to pi

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thanks after making this change, I was able to obtain $\pi^2$.

Comment: @HenryLee I see was going on behind, thanks for the explanation